# JSON Parser throwing error, problem in json string

Tags: iphone, json, parsing

This is the string that I am passing to the SBJsonStreamParser

> {"ID":"6","UserID":"8","WeighedOn":"2/11/2011
>   ","Weight":"73.5"},{"ID":"9","UserID":"8","WeighedOn":"2/14/2011
>   ","Weight":"73.5"},{"ID":"15","UserID":"8","WeighedOn":"2/15/2011
>   ","Weight":"73.5"},{"ID":"25","UserID":"8","WeighedOn":"2/16/2011
>   ","Weight":"73.5"},{"ID":"46","UserID":"8","WeighedOn":"2/18/2011
>   ","Weight":"161.7"},{"ID":"47","UserID":"8","WeighedOn":"2/21/2011
>   ","Weight":"161.7"},{"ID":"99","UserID":"8","WeighedOn":"2/22/2011
>   ","Weight":"161.82"},{"ID":"134","UserID":"8","WeighedOn":"2/23/2011","Weight":"198"},{"ID":"158","UserID":"8","WeighedOn":"2/25/2011
>   ","Weight":"199.65"},{"ID":"189","UserID":"8","WeighedOn":"2/28/2011
>   ","Weight":"166.17"},{"ID":"220","UserID":"8","WeighedOn":"3/1/2011
>   ","Weight":"60"},{"ID":"231","UserID":"8","WeighedOn":"3/2/2011
>   ","Weight":"165"},{"ID":"271","UserID":"8","WeighedOn":"3/3/2011
>   ","Weight":"220"},{"ID":"281","UserID":"8","WeighedOn":"3/4/2011
>   ","Weight":"220"},{"ID":"302","UserID":"8","WeighedOn":"3/7/2011
>   ","Weight":"166.1"},{"ID":"316","UserID":"8","WeighedOn":"3/9/2011
>   ","Weight":"166.1"},{"ID":"325","UserID":"8","WeighedOn":"3/10/2011","Weight":"70"},{"ID":"334","UserID":"8","WeighedOn":"3/11/2011
>   ","Weight":"70"},{"ID":"343","UserID":"8","WeighedOn":"3/14/2011
>   ","Weight":"70"},{"ID":"353","UserID":"8","WeighedOn":"3/15/2011
>   ","Weight":"70"},{"ID":"358","UserID":"8","WeighedOn":"3/16/2011
>   ","Weight":"70"},{"ID":"371","UserID":"8","WeighedOn":"3/23/2011","Weight":"198"},{"ID":"377","UserID":"8","WeighedOn":"3/24/2011","Weight":"99"},{"ID":"437","UserID":"8","WeighedOn":"3/25/2011
>   ","Weight":"160"},{"ID":"472","UserID":"8","WeighedOn":"4/1/2011
>   ","Weight":"180"}

I am converting it to data and parsing it, using the following code

```
str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"ID\":\"6\",\"UserID\":\"8\",\"WeighedOn\":\"2/11/2011 \",\"Weight\":\"73.5\"},{\"ID\":\"9\",\"UserID\":\"8\",\"WeighedOn\":\"2/14/2011 \",\"Weight\":\"73.5\"},{\"ID\":\"15\",\"UserID\":\"8\",\"WeighedOn\":\"2/15/2011 \",\"Weight\":\"73.5\"},{\"ID\":\"25\",\"UserID\":\"8\",\"WeighedOn\":\"2/16/2011 \",\"Weight\":\"73.5\"},{\"ID\":\"46\",\"UserID\":\"8\",\"WeighedOn\":\"2/18/2011 \",\"Weight\":\"161.7\"},{\"ID\":\"47\",\"UserID\":\"8\",\"WeighedOn\":\"2/21/2011 \",\"Weight\":\"161.7\"},{\"ID\":\"99\",\"UserID\":\"8\",\"WeighedOn\":\"2/22/2011 \",\"Weight\":\"161.82\"},{\"ID\":\"134\",\"UserID\":\"8\",\"WeighedOn\":\"2/23/2011\",\"Weight\":\"198\"},{\"ID\":\"158\",\"UserID\":\"8\",\"WeighedOn\":\"2/25/2011 \",\"Weight\":\"199.65\"},{\"ID\":\"189\",\"UserID\":\"8\",\"WeighedOn\":\"2/28/2011 \",\"Weight\":\"166.17\"},{\"ID\":\"220\",\"UserID\":\"8\",\"WeighedOn\":\"3/1/2011 \",\"Weight\":\"60\"},{\"ID\":\"231\",\"UserID\":\"8\",\"WeighedOn\":\"3/2/2011 \",\"Weight\":\"165\"},{\"ID\":\"271\",\"UserID\":\"8\",\"WeighedOn\":\"3/3/2011 \",\"Weight\":\"220\"},{\"ID\":\"281\",\"UserID\":\"8\",\"WeighedOn\":\"3/4/2011 \",\"Weight\":\"220\"},{\"ID\":\"302\",\"UserID\":\"8\",\"WeighedOn\":\"3/7/2011 \",\"Weight\":\"166.1\"},{\"ID\":\"316\",\"UserID\":\"8\",\"WeighedOn\":\"3/9/2011 \",\"Weight\":\"166.1\"},{\"ID\":\"325\",\"UserID\":\"8\",\"WeighedOn\":\"3/10/2011\",\"Weight\":\"70\"},{\"ID\":\"334\",\"UserID\":\"8\",\"WeighedOn\":\"3/11/2011 \",\"Weight\":\"70\"},{\"ID\":\"343\",\"UserID\":\"8\",\"WeighedOn\":\"3/14/2011 \",\"Weight\":\"70\"},{\"ID\":\"353\",\"UserID\":\"8\",\"WeighedOn\":\"3/15/2011 \",\"Weight\":\"70\"},{\"ID\":\"358\",\"UserID\":\"8\",\"WeighedOn\":\"3/16/2011 \",\"Weight\":\"70\"},{\"ID\":\"371\",\"UserID\":\"8\",\"WeighedOn\":\"3/23/2011\",\"Weight\":\"198\"},{\"ID\":\"377\",\"UserID\":\"8\",\"WeighedOn\":\"3/24/2011\",\"Weight\":\"99\"},{\"ID\":\"437\",\"UserID\":\"8\",\"WeighedOn\":\"3/25/2011 \",\"Weight\":\"160\"},{\"ID\":\"472\",\"UserID\":\"8\",\"WeighedOn\":\"4/1/2011 \",\"Weight\":\"180\"}"];
NSLog(@"Str: %@",str);

NSData * data1 = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
data = data1;

SBJsonStreamParserStatus status = [parser parse:data];
```

But I am getting following error, whenever I am parsing it.

> Parser error: Token 'value separator'
>   not expected before outer-most array
>   or object

Can you guys tell me, what is it, which is wrong?

Comment: In IOS 5.0 Apple included the NSJSONSerialization class to convert JSON to Foundation objects and convert Foundation objects to JSON. 
Check out http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/ for the details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a complete JSON data structure. Ther data contains "," delimiters after each "}".

Check with [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) for more details.

Comment: Awesome tool to have in your programming arsenal. Thanks for your post.